# LibGDX: Reading from json file to ArrayList

Tags: java, json, libgdx

I need help with reading json file to ArrayList.

I have json file:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Wall",
        "symbol": "#",      
    },
    {
        "name": "Floor",
        "symbol": ".",
    }
]
```

I have a class:

```
public class Tile {

    public String name;
    public String symbol;

}
```

And I have another class with ArrayList:

```
public class Data {

    public static ArrayList<Tile> tilesData;

    public static void loadData() {
        tilesData = new ArrayList<Tile>();
        Json json = new Json();
        json.fromJson(Tile.class, Gdx.files.internal("data/tiles.json"));
    }

}
```

I need to fill this ArrayList with data from json file, but I have some problems. I guess the line

```
json.fromJson(Tile.class, Gdx.files.internal("data/tiles.json"));
```

is wrong.

When I try to run it there is

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: data/tiles.json

Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Unable to convert value to required type: [
{
    name: Wall,
    symbol: #
},
{
    name: Floor,
    symbol: .
}
```

I have read the libgdx article about json files, but I found it unclear... I don't understand how to fill array. Please, help me with this case!

Comment: What do you mean by "some problems" ? Compilation or runtime errors ? Can you post it ?

Comment: I've edited my post. As I know, I have mistake in parsing json file to my array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your json file has `ArrayList<Tile>` stored in it and you are trying to read it as a `Tile`.

There are two ways to rectify this.

1) You can encapsulate collection of tiles in another class to simplify serialization.

2) Read as `ArrayList` and convert type later.

```
ArrayList<JsonValue> list = json.fromJson(ArrayList.class,
                                          Gdx.files.internal("data/tiles.json"));
for (JsonValue v : list) {
    tilesData.add(json.readValue(Tile.class, v));
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you please tell me more about how to typecast this? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Glad to know it helped.

Answer (score 9):

The answer from Tanmay Patil is right but you can save the loop with:

```
ArrayList<Tile> board = json.fromJson(ArrayList.class, Tile.class, Gdx.files.internal("data/tiles.json"));
```

Comment: Thank you, it is very usefull addition

Comment: Holy crap.  I just reduced my original JSON loading code from 10 lines down to 1.  LibGDX is pretty sweet.

Comment: I just came across this post, which is somewhat related to my questions. Instead of reading the json file, is it possible to write the json string ( posted in original question) to the file ? I see class information also printed in the serialized json file, which I don't want. My ques link : http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/125307/unable-to-remove-class-information-in-serialized-json-file-using-libgdx

Comment: @user2582651 I answered your question, hope it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Tile> board = json.fromJson(ArrayList.class, Tile.class,
    Gdx.files.internal("data/tiles.json").readString());
```

2 years and the libgdx has changed a little, so to managed to make it work. Now we have to add `.readString()`. I was stuck until I figured this out.